# "Lost Connection to Database" during Rails Migration?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am building an app with Ruby/Rails and using a MySQL database.

Recently, I started having the following issue: sometimes, when doing a Rails migration, Rails **drops** my DB table!

When it drops the table it gives the following error:

```
"MySQL2:error: Lost connection to MySQL server during query: ALTER TABLE . . ."
```

My internet connection is good. It has happened twice so far. The first time the migration involved the following methods: `remove_column`, `add_column`, `add_foreign_key`. The second time it contained only `remove_column` and `add_column`.

The migrations are not huge files with a maximum of 10 lines.

Why is it doing this? What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Maybe your MySQL process is crashing. Check the logs. Also run your migrations as close as possible to where the MySQL server resides. Using a remote connection can be trouble.

Comment: Interesting--why would the remote connection cause trouble?

Comment: I recently ran into the same issue with MySQL dropping the connection when altering a table.  Restarting MySQL would not fix the issue.  Turned out to be a corrupt table.  Dropping and recreating the database was the only way to fix it.

Comment: @infused-thank you. Do you know the nature/cause of the corruption?

Comment: @Jo.P You might have a router or firewall that aggressively drops idle connections.

Comment: @Jo.P, I don't know why/how it got corrupted but accessing 4 out of my 155 tables caused MySQL to drop the connection each time.  Trying to run "CHECK TABLE" on any of those tables would hang indefinitely.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help! Looking into it.